# Log Flush Policy for Kafka brokers in production systems

Tags: apache-kafka

What are the appropriate values for the following Kafka broker properties for a production system?

> log.flush.interval.messages
>   log.flush.interval.ms

I am seeing too many small IOs write requests in my st1 HDD drive which I would like to optimize. Will changing these properties help? What are the tradeoffs?
Also, How are these properties configured in any typical production system?

We have 5 Kafka brokers (r5.xlarge) with attached st1 HDD Drive. Our usual data input rate is around 2 Mbps during peak time and 700-800 Kbps during usual time.

Comment: "Production" grade systems vary from company to company.... Netflix has trillions of events. Other companies are less than 1 billion in production. I don't think there is a single answer for this, and it also depends on your hardware profiles

Comment: I have added hardware config in the question. 
I am more interested in knowing if I should alter these values from default in order to reduce the number of IOs. It is worth to change these values considering the tradeoffs.

Comment: I guess that depends on your thoughput. If you have millions of messages per second, then increasing the `ms` interval would of course cause less flushes